# Two dimensional array mapping in point free notation?

Tags: javascript, arrays, functional-programming, ramda.js

I'm playing around with functional/tacit style programming, specifically creating the snake game (example of game: http://patorjk.com/games/snake/)

The specific question is that I'm taking an array of strings like:

```
[
 ['2 '],
 ['10']
]
```

and wanting to get the list of coordinates in numerical order of the 'value'. In the domain, 0 is the head of the snake, 2 is the tail, the whole thing is the board.

So I built:

```
var findSnake = function(rendered_board) {
  return r.map(function(x) {
    return r.map(function (y) {
      return {
        x: x,
        y: y,
        val: rendered_board[x][y]
      };
    })(r.keys(r.split('', rendered_board[x])));
  })(r.keys(rendered_board));
};
```

which gives me back:

`[ [ { x: '0', y: '0', val: '2' }, { x: '0', y: '1', val: ' ' } ],
  [ { x: '1', y: '0', val: '1' }, { x: '1', y: '1', val: '0' } ] ]`

which I can then sort and get my list of coordinates. It works but I have questions on style.

Is there a way to write findSnake in point free style? Is there a more idiomatic approach to this problem?

Comment: Have you had a l look at http://ramdajs.com/0.17/docs/#mapObjIndexed and http://ramdajs.com/0.17/docs/#addIndex?

Comment: @Bergi No, I haven't. I'm new to the library so still plenty to learn. Thanks, I'll definitely explore these in my solution!

Comment: Actually I was expecting to find a `R.mapIndexed`, but that doesn't seem to be available. Iirc, they deprecated it in favour of `addIndex`.

Comment: @Bergi: Correct.  All the list-based functions that had `index` / `list` parameters after a callback were removed in favor of a general-purpose `addIndex` decorator which converts a simpler function into one like that.  E.g. `var mapIndexed = R.addIndex(R.map)`.  We didn't bother with the few non-list functions like `mapObjIndexed`.

Comment: @ScottSauyet: Care to write an answer? I'd love to see how you make this point-free :-)

Comment: @Bergi: I just looked it over, and don't see any easy way.  I'm also the one ever suggesting that people don't make a fetish of points-free, so I suppose I have an excuse.  :-)  But now I want to see what I can do.  Maybe I'll have some time to dig into it later in the day.

Comment: @ScottSauyet I'm learning so was interested in making this point free because I couldn't see how to do it :) Sounds like this wouldn't make sense in a production code base? Is this approach readable to you? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As expected, this seems far too difficult to turn into a readable points-free solution.  I did take a simpler subset of it, just to see what I could do, and that itself was ugly enough that I didn't carry it through.

If we started with this function:

```
var fn = function(list) {
    return R.map(function(y) {
        return {
            y: y
        };
    }, list);
}
```

... which can clearly be recognized as an inner subproblem of the original, then, I can turn it into this monstrosity:

```
var fn = R.pipe(R.converge(
    R.zip, 
    R.pipe(R.length, R.repeat('y')), 
    R.identity
), R.map(R.apply(R.createMapEntry)));
```

(Some intermediate steps are in the **[REPL](http://ramdajs.com/repl/#?code=%5B%0A%20%20%0AR.map%28function%28y%29%20%7B%0A%20%20return%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20y%3A%20y%0A%20%20%7D%3B%0A%7D%2C%20%5B1%2C%202%2C%203%5D%29%2C%0A%20%20%0AR.map%28R.apply%28R.createMapEntry%29%2C%20R.zip%28R.repeat%28%27y%27%2C%203%29%2C%20%5B1%2C%202%2C%203%5D%29%29%2C%0A%0AR.map%28R.apply%28R.createMapEntry%29%2C%20R.zip%28R.repeat%28%27y%27%2C%203%29%29%28%5B1%2C%202%2C%203%5D%29%29%2C%0A%20%0AR.pipe%28R.zip%28R.repeat%28%27y%27%2C%203%29%29%2C%20R.map%28R.apply%28R.createMapEntry%29%29%29%28%5B1%2C%202%2C%203%5D%29%2C%0A%0AR.pipe%28R.converge%28R.zip%2C%20R.pipe%28R.length%2C%20R.repeat%28%27y%27%29%29%2C%20R.identity%29%2C%20R.map%28R.apply%28R.createMapEntry%29%29%29%28%5B1%2C%202%2C%203%5D%29%2C%0A%0AR.map%28y%20%3D%3E%20%28%7By%7D%29%2C%20%5B1%2C%202%2C%203%5D%29%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%5D)**)

But considering how this looks in es6, that seems extremely counter-productive:

```
var fn = R.map(y => ({y});
```

And that's why I use points-free when it makes sense, but don't try to apply it everywhere.

---

**Update**

As of [version 0.18](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/issues/1436), Ramda renamed `createMapEntry` to `objOf` made `converge` a binary function, which means the code above no longer works.  Nor does the REPL link, as the REPL has been updated.  You can see it now updated in the **[REPL](http://ramdajs.com/repl/#?code=%5B%0A%20%20%0AR.map%28function%28y%29%20%7B%0A%20%20return%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20y%3A%20y%0A%20%20%7D%3B%0A%7D%2C%20%5B1%2C%202%2C%203%5D%29%2C%0A%20%20%0AR.map%28R.apply%28R.objOf%29%2C%20R.zip%28R.repeat%28%27y%27%2C%203%29%2C%20%5B1%2C%202%2C%203%5D%29%29%2C%0A%0AR.map%28R.apply%28R.objOf%29%2C%20R.zip%28R.repeat%28%27y%27%2C%203%29%29%28%5B1%2C%202%2C%203%5D%29%29%2C%0A%20%0AR.pipe%28R.zip%28R.repeat%28%27y%27%2C%203%29%29%2C%20R.map%28R.apply%28R.objOf%29%29%29%28%5B1%2C%202%2C%203%5D%29%2C%0A%0AR.pipe%28R.converge%28R.zip%2C%20%5BR.pipe%28R.length%2C%20R.repeat%28%27y%27%29%29%2C%20R.identity%5D%29%2C%20R.map%28R.apply%28R.objOf%29%29%29%28%5B1%2C%202%2C%203%5D%29%2C%0A%0AR.map%28y%20%3D%3E%20%28%7By%7D%29%2C%20%5B1%2C%202%2C%203%5D%29%0A%20%20%0A%5D)**.